# Heatmap plots using coordinate and intensity data

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have a data set of 3 arrays where I have the x-y coordinates and the intensity. I am trying to plot this data using seaborn's heatmap function, but I couldn't figure out how to plot the intensity with respect to the x-y coordinates, because `seaborn.heatmap` only accepts one argument for data. Here is an MWE:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn

x=np.array([-1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 2, -2, 0, 2, -2, -2, 2])
y=np.array([1, 1, -1, -1, 2, 0, 0, -2, 2, 2, -2, -2])
J=np.array([-0.019, -0.019, -0.019, -0.019, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012])
sn.heatmap(J.reshape(3,4))
plt.show()
```

What I really want to do is to plot `J[i]` with respect to `x[i]` and `y[i]`. Can I zip the x-y positions and somehow relate them to `J` array? I don't have to use seaborn, but I need to use interpolation methods (i.e. `matplotlib.imshow()` would also work).

All the examples I can find use random generators which don't target plotting on specific grid points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organize the data in a `pd.DataFrame` and `.pivot()` them:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x=np.array([-1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 2, -2, 0, 2, -2, -2, 2])
y=np.array([1, 1, -1, -1, 2, 0, 0, -2, 2, 2, -2, -2])
J=np.array([-0.019, -0.019, -0.019, -0.019, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, -0.09, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012, 0.012])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, intensity=J))

sns.heatmap(df.pivot('x', 'y', 'intensity'), annot=True)
plt.show()
```